# Multiple Jobs running on ThreadPool with infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I have to try to understand the ThreadPool Management with Quartz.

I have one scenario which is not clear to me.Please try to help me with the given scenario below.

I have 2 jobs lets say Job1 and Job2 and sharing ThreadPool of 10 Threads.
Job1 will run in infinite loop and Job2 will just run some simple logic like any print statement.
AS Job1 will run infinite loop so Thread using by Job1 will stuck and it will never come back to ThreadPool,Even if I interrupt the Thread1 it will reduce the size of ThreadPool to 9 Threads.

now When All Thread are interrupted then there will be no Thread in Thread pool for Job2 to run.
So question here is that how I interrupt the thread running for Job1 from long time and send it back to thread pool by which Job2 can access that thread>

Any Solution is more appreciate!!